# How to fix Delphi XE2 error: Package can't be installed because it was created with a different version of Delphi or CBuilder?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have just build EmbeddedWebBrowser_XE2.dpk and after that trying to install it - all by context menu on the project inside IDE. And get the error:

`Package can't be installed because it was created with a different version of Delphi or CBuilder?`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: i am facing the same issue on a bpl that I think was for XE and am facing with this msg...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a updated xe2 version of the embeddedweb browser..  I was fighting with the same error.  I did some research on this issue and it seems that perhaps the XE2 Update 2 is breaking other components from other companies.  Are you running Update 2?  I should of tried to install the package before I updated to update3....So i will not fully know if the update 2 is the issue... and now that new source is available... All is not to be worried about.

but I did find updated sources that fixes this... I would suggest you just get the updated package and not look back.

google:  Embedded Web Browser xe2

5th link down.... russians love delphi

Embedded Web Browser v14.70.0 D5-XE2 Все для ..

whoo hooo.

Answer (score 0):

'IEConst' unit name is restricted in Delphi XE2. Rename the unit to fix the issue.